# how to write an if statement code to compare two cell's value in one sheet to another cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have two columns (Start Date, End Date) and i want a code that changes the color of both their cells to red if the start date and end date contained any date located in another sheet

I tried using conditional formatting using this rule: =AND(C2<=Holidays!$A$2:$A$15,D2>=Holidays!$A$2:$A$15)

Comment: Is the conditional formatting tool not enough?

Comment: i tried using it but i had to enter a rule for every date and only Startdate cells turns to red

Answer (score 0):

Tested out the below formula for myself and think it should work! Effectively rather than a simple AND statement, since we're comparing against an array of values rather than single cells, we need to use some handy array formulas. This post gives a good breakdown of what's going on under the hood: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Apply this formula in conditional formatting, assuming the range you're formatting starts at C2.

```
=SUM((Holidays!$A$2:$A$15>$C2)*(Holidays!$A$2:$A$15<$D2)) > 0
```

Also, wanted to call out the absolute references specified for columns. I've specified **$**C2 and **$**D2 in my formula, which means that no matter which cell in your conditional formatted range it'll evaluate off the values in column C and D. In your current formula, cell C2, would evaluate on C2 and D2, but cell D2 would then evaluate off D2 and E2. This'd be why when you tried the manual formatting only the start date cells (column C) were formatting correctly.

Hope this helps!

Update::

If you had a table format like in the attached screenshot, you would apply the conditional formatting formula:

=SUM((Holidays!$A$2:$A$15>$C2)*(Holidays!$A$2:$A$15< $D2)) > 0

To cell range $C$2 : $D$3

If you're changing the cell range (say you wanted to apply to $C$10 : $D$14), you'd just change the $C2 and $D2 in the formula --> $C10 and $D10.

[image: Sample pic]

Comment: this rule seems to work only on two different cells but when i apply it to C2 and D2 their colors doesn't change ..is it because C2 and D2 are within a table?

Comment: *i've used the same rule but chose different cells under "Applies to" in the conditional formatting

Comment: the cells that got their color change are the cells above the ones that contains the date of the holidays ..i don't understand excel's logic at this point, i've used the same rule and cell range as above

Comment: the task has been handed to a programmer, thank you for your effort.

Comment: That's an issue with your relative references then. If your range starts in row 1, you need to change the formula to =SUM((Holidays!$A$2:$A$15>$C1)*(Holidays!$A$2:$A$15< $D1)) > 0. If your range starts in row 2, =SUM((Holidays!$A$2:$A$15>$C2)*(Holidays!$A$2:$A$15< $D2)) > 0, and so forth