# How to search 2 values on another Sheet and then based on that return a specific cell from the same row as them back on the 1st Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I was thinking of a **double VBA VLOOKUP or a double conditional** If for that 2 cells and return another cell from the specific row back on Sheet1.

Basically a double VBA VLOOKUP or a double conditional IF when the strings were found
I'd be going with the VLOOKUP in VBA , sort of look for A2 and D2 from Sheet 1 in Sheet 2 Range `A1:A999` and `D2:D999` and if the results match output C cell from the same row back on C2 in Sheet 1

But not sure how to proceed further. Any advice would be more than appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Output on the yellow Cell]

[image: Sheet2 where the VBA VLOOKUP will take place]

Comment: did you try to use range.find method? Helpful link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff839746(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: you mean age is not a string?

Comment: Relevant? see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59973808/4961700

Comment: Numbers can be considered as strings if they are in double quotes/string's quotes irrespective of the programming language

Answer (score 0):

The following vba macro might be of help:

```
Sub lookupMatch()
    Dim TotalCols As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Copy matched up values from sheet2 to sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Changed Cols to Columns on the above line.

    Range("C1:C" & TotalCols).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")

    'destination sheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    For i = 1 To TotalCols
        'Search for the value on sheet2
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 3).Value)
        'If found put its value on destination sheet
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Doable entirely without VBA:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$999, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999)/(--(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999=$A1)*--(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999=$B1)), 1), 1)
```

The obvious bit is the `Index` - replace the `AGGREGATE` with a `MATCH`, and you probably already recognise it:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$999, MATCH(???), 1)
```

However, instead of using `MATCH`, we are using [the `AGGREGATE` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999)/(--(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999=$A1)*--(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999=$B1)), 1)
```

1. The first argument (`15`) just tells us to look for the *k<sup>th</sup>* **SMALL**est value in a list.  This is similar to using the `SMALL` function
2. The second argument (`6`) tells us to **discard any error values** in the list.
3. The third argument is the list to look at - we'll break this down later
4. The final argument (`1`) tells us to get the 1<sup>st</sup> smallest value from the list - effectively `MIN`, but `MIN` doesn't play nicely with calculated lists

So, what is our List then.  Let's look at the formula:

```
ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999)/(--(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999=$A1)*--(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999=$B1))
```

There are two important parts here - first, `ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999)` will output the row number that we want, so that we can use it in the `INDEX`.  Secondly, we divide it by a value which will be `1` when Column A matches (`--(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999=$A1)`) **and** Column B matches (`--(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999=$B1)`), but `0` when either of them doesn't.  And, anything divided by 0 gives a `#DIV0!` error - which means it is discarded from our list!

So, the output of the `AGGREGATE` is the smallest Row number where the values match.  If there is *no such row*, then you will get a `#NUM!` error instead.

Comment: So what about the second condition regarding D2 cell from Sheet1 to be found on Sheet2?

Comment: @Gordon ...  Have you tried just changing the columns it looks at?  `INDEX(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$999` will pull the gender, while `--(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$999=$D1)` would search for it.  (Do note that you haven't labelled which of your pictures is `Sheet1` or `Sheet2` in the question)

Comment: The picture with a yellow cell is Sheet 1 and the 2nd picture is Sheet2. I am trying to do this by using VBA. Thanks !