# Matching data between two sheets and copy to location

Tags: excel, vba

This is the scenario:

- two worksheets - Sheet1 & Sheet2
- Sheet1 has everything Sheet2 has and more

I am looking to find an exact match in Sheet1 Column A and B to data in Sheet2 Columns A and B (row location will always be different than Sheet1) and then copy the contents of column C from sheet 1 to the appropriate row in Sheet2 column C.

I have tried multiple `Match` statements. I am getting all kinds of errors and cannot even get an incorrect result.

Sheet1 is the primary table. Sheet2 is a subset of data from Sheet1 (the results of a pivot table drill-down. The idea is to look at each row, columns A & B in Sheet2 and find a match in Cols A & B of Sheet1. Then copy the value from the same row in column C to the corresponding row in Sheet2.

This was one attempt:

```
Sub match_1() 
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match( _
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value, _
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B"), _
        0) 
End Sub
```

Sheet1:
[image: This is sheet1]

Sheet2:
[image: This is sheet2]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This was one attempt: Sub match_1()


Sheets("Sheet14").Range("A2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A2").Value, Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A:A"), 0)



End Sub

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that code instead of posting in a comment, thanks.

Comment: Please also include your input data and expected output when you edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with how you are using [the `Match` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a):

1. `Match` expects a *single* row or column of data in the second argument.  You have passed it 2 columns, so it will **always** return a `#N/A` error
2. `Match` returns the **item number** within the Row/Column which matches the first argument.  You then need to use `Index` or `Range` or `Cell` to get the value.
3. `Match` does **not** match multiple columns.  I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59985422/9290986) how to do this match *without* VBA

Using my example from Point 3, here is some code to achieve your aim:

```
Sub matchValues()
    Dim calculation As XlCalculation, screenUpdating As Boolean
    calculation = Application.calculation: Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
    screenUpdating = Application.screenUpdating: Application.screenUpdating = False

    Dim rCaseLink As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set rCaseLink = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
    End With

    With rCaseLink
        'This formula will pull back the Value for Column C based on A and B
        .Formula = "=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$999, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999)/(--(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999=$A2)*--(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$999=$B2)), 1)-1, 1)"
        .Calculate
        .Value = .Value 'This will flatten the value, so that it is no longer a formula
    End With

    'Reset Excel
    Application.calculation = calculation
    Application.screenUpdating = screenUpdating
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - this help a lot. One item I have noticed is that it strips out hyperlink data during the copy/paste from one sheet to the other. I will research that to see if I can find out why - but if you have an answer fro that one it would be super helpful as well.